# Inquiry on std::binary_search()

Tags: c++, list, indexing, compare, binary-search

I'm currently looking at using std::binary_search() (from the  library) to determine whether or not an instance of something exists in a list. I want to know how it works before I begin using it.

My understanding is that it uses comparison (and for user-defined structs/classes it would need access to a user-defined compare function) to find out if an instance of an object exists within a list/vector. According to this website (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/), the range that is used is:

```
[first, last)
```

So is it not *including* **last** because it would have to compare **last** against **last + 1**?

Also the user-defined compare function's logic does not matter as long as it differentiates between properties within the object/class. Is that correct?

For example, if my struct/class consisted of the following:

```
coord
{
    int X;
    int Y;
}
```

I would have to make sure that my compare function differentiates (in some manner, such as greater-than/less-than comparison) the X and Y properties of elements a and b in the list/vector.

Comment: A better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::binary_search() is implemented as a common binary search algorithm, it performs at most log2(N)+1 element comparisons. (for more information on how binary search is implemented check this [link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/))

> So is it not including last because it would have to compare last against last + 1?

No, the reason is just to facilitate its use. You can call the function as:

```
std::binary_search (v.begin(), v.end(), 42)
```

Notice that v.end() returns an iterator to the element past the end of the sequence. Hence, it does not point to any element, and thus shall not be evaluated in the search.

> Also the user-defined compare function's logic does not matter as long as it differentiates between properties within the object/class. Is that correct?

The compare function it is used for the binary_search() in order to know if the element you are looking for is before the element currently being tested of after it. In other words, the compare function must be able to compare two elements and return if the first one is "lower" than the second one (must be placed in the container before the second one).

For your Coord example you could write a comparator function like:

```
struct lessThanKey
{
    inline bool operator() (const Coord& lhs, const Coord& rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.x < rhs.x) || ((lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y < rhs.y));
    }
};

std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), Coord{42, 42}, lessThanKey());
```

Comment: That makes more sense. And the answer below confirms my thought that I would have to sort the list (prior to searching in it) using the same compare function.

Comment: Exactly, to use `std::binary_search` the container must be sorted. If you want to check for the existence of an element in an unsorted container you can use `if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(),value) != v.end())`

Answer (score 1):

The range does **not** include the *last* element as a general library convention and it means that the distance between *first* and *last* iterators equals the number of elements in the range and also that the range can be tested for in a loop using:

```
while(first != last)
{
    // process stuff
    ++first;
}
```

The `std::binary_search` must be carried out on *sorted* data that was sorted using the same (possibly user defined) *compare* function.

That function needs to establish a *less than* relationship between two elements.

```
struct coord
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct CoordComparator
{
    bool operator()(const coord& lhs, const coord& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x ? lhs.y < rhs.y : lhs.x < rhs.x;
    }
};

std::vector<coord> v { {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2} };

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), CoordComparator());

if(std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), coord{2, 1}, CoordComparator()))
{
    // element found in range
}
```

That *less than* relationship can be defined such that *greater* values are reported to be *less than* lower values to give a reverse sorted relationship.

Comment: After reading the answer above, I was wondering if I would have to sort the list before I searched through it (and if I would have to use the same compare function to do it). I somehow forgot about my lessons on how binary searching works. Thank you for confirming my thoughts!